# Connect node.js to Azure Subscription

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-powershell

If you're using Powershell you can connect directly to an Azure Keyvault with

```
$kv = Get-AzureRmKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VaultName $vaultName
```

Is there something similar with node.js? What is the most efficient way to connect node to a Keyvault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something similar with node.js?

No, they are different. Based on my understanding, Key vault is a kind of Azure resource. Node.js is a server-side platform built on Google Chrome's JavaScript Engine (V8 Engine). Azure provides powershell for users to connect Azure KeyVault. But if you want to connect keyvault with Node.js. You should use Azure SDK for Node.js.

**Authentication**

```
var KeyVault = require('azure-keyvault');
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var clientId = "<to-be-filled>";
var clientSecret = "<to-be-filled>";
var vaultUri = "<to-be-filled>";

// Authenticator - retrieves the access token 
var authenticator = function (challenge, callback) {

  // Create a new authentication context. 
  var context = new AuthenticationContext(challenge.authorization);

  // Use the context to acquire an authentication token. 
  return context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(challenge.resource, clientId, clientSecret, function (err, tokenResponse) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // Calculate the value to be set in the request's Authorization header and resume the call. 
    var authorizationValue = tokenResponse.tokenType + ' ' + tokenResponse.accessToken;

    return callback(null, authorizationValue);
  });

};
```

More information about this, please refer to this [link:Microsoft Azure SDK for Node.js - Key Vault](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-keyvault).

Comment: I've actually looked at this already, but I can't confirm whether or not I'm connecting. I'm not getting any errors, but is there a way I can use it to output secrets from a vault that already exists? I don't want to create a vault or a key, I just want to list info from the vault to make sure I'm connected.

Comment: @user3364161 You could list all secrets in your key vault. You could check SDK. `client.setSecret(vaultUri, 'mysecret', 'my password', options, function (err, secretBundle)`.